# subprocess.Popen with docker -c command

Tags: python, subprocess, dockerpy

Why
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
is not working for such command?

['docker', 'exec', 'hungry_keller', 'bash', '-c', ' ""ls -l""]
docker exec hungry_keller bash -c "ls -l"

and returns:
No such file or directory

subprocess.check_output returns the same error.

but in terminal it executes correctly. More simple commands are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've been overzealous with your quoting. When you type at the shell prompt `bash -c "ls -l"`, you're using the quotes to tell bash that `ls -l` is a single token. Those quotes aren't actually seen by `bash` at all; it simply receives two arguments:

1. `-c`
2. `ls -l`

When calling `subprocess` methods with a list, you're already being explicit about your tokenization because you're providing a list of strings. So instead of:

```
subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'exec', 'hungry_keller', 'bash', '-c', ' ""ls -l""] )
```

You want:

```
subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'exec', 'hungry_keller', 'bash', '-c', 'ls -l'] )
```